# why sitecolumn title is blank after feature activation

Tags: feature, column

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem with defining Site Columns in a feature](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/2463/problem-with-defining-site-columns-in-a-feature)

1. After installing using stsadmin, and activating using site UI "Site Collection Feature"
   these columns shows up but no title is showing for them. So no link is attached. It looks like this.

   Site Column Type Source 
   Car Custom Columns 
       Single line of text SiteCol1
       Single line of text SiteCol1 
       Single line of text SiteCol1
       Date and Time SiteCol1

here is feature.xml

```
<Feature Id="{32112c0f-5640-49f6-9741-d43d3d02037f}" 
  Title="Custom Site Columns" 
  Description="Adding Custom Columns" 
  Version="1.0.0.0" 
  Scope="Site" 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ElementManifests>
    <ElementManifest Location="elements.xml" />
  </ElementManifests>
</Feature>
```

here is elements.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Field Type="Text" 
         Required="FALSE" 
         MaxLength="255" 
         Group="Car Custom Columns" 
         ID="{50eece5f-a683-4d1f-8e6a-a661fac980f6}" 
         Name="Car_VinNumber" 
         DisplayName="VIN Number"                 
         StaticName="Car_VinNumber" 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  </Field>
</Elements>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the issue you're experiencing based off of your explination.  Can you please provide additional details to help me understand?  Thanks.

Comment: The site columns are showing up in the site settings but their title are missing. therefore, i cant click on the column. I wish i could post a snapshot of the site so it would makes sense.

Comment: DisplayName is not showing up in the setting page. and the link to specific column is thru this display name. I can see all 6 site columns using spm manager 2007 (in the field area with blank field). i can go in each field this way and repopulated displayname and save and then they show up under the site setting area with link. hmm

Comment: I can't see the feature xml or the elements xml. You might like to try editing to insert a code block with the xml

Comment: I really hate when people from this site modifies my originally post. I added both xml files and now they are gone. great.

Comment: No one has edited your post... When you paste xml, don't paste directly into the box, use the 'Code Sample' button on the toolbar to insert the xml text